# How to declare a variable globally so that it's visible for all perl modules?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Hi I have a perl script named main.pl. This perl script is calling three perl modules named `sub1.pm`, `sub2.pm`, and `sub3.pm`. `sub.pm` is returning three hashes which are being used in `sub2.pm` and `sub3.pm`. I am passing the hashes as input parameter to sub2 and sub3. Instead is there any way that I can declare the hashes globally so that it will be visible to these two perl modules?

Comment: Probably, but this is almost certainly an XY problem - the whole point of using modules is isolating namespaces and you're trying to subvert that. Step back, and look at what you're _actually trying to accomplish_

Comment: Passing the hashes as parameters to `sub2()` and `sub3()` sounds like exactly the right thing to do. It's very unlikely that using global variables will give you a better-engineered solution.

Comment: I hope they're actually called `Sub1.pm`, `Sub2.pm` and `Sub3.pm` or dieally something much more descriptive? Lower-case package names are reserved for *pragmas*

Answer (score 3):

When you declare non-global variables, it is done by putting "my" in front of it. i.e.:

`my $local_variable = 4;`

What you are wanting to do is replace the "my" with "our" and make sure it is placed outside of a subroutine. i.e.:

`our $global_variable = 4;`

If you wish to use it in other modules, you can add it by the following:

`use vars qw($global_variable);`

Now that I told you how to do it, I am going to tell you not to do it. It is strongly discouraged to use global variables. You should use local variables whenever you can. The reason for this is because if you are ever working on a larger project or a project with multiple coders, then you might find unknown errors as certain variables might not equal what you expect them to because they were changed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable you declare in a module XY with

```
our $var;
our %hash;
```

or

```
use vars qw($var %hash);
```

is declared global and available as

```
$XY::var
%XY::hash;
```

in every other perl-module (if the module has already been used/required).

HTH

Comment: sorry I am a novice in perl. what is this XY?

Comment: The package name. But if you're a novice with perl, that's even more reason why this is a bad idea.

Comment: So if you have your global variable in your calling script %hash1 (which implicit is the package main) you would declare it with our %hash1; and use it as %main::hash1 in the subs. (or $main::hash1{key1} for that...)

Comment: I don't understand why this is a bad idea. let's say I have around 10 subroutines. Instead of passing it every time it's better to make them visible globally right.

Comment: I guess you probably should/could write another package (maybe as a singleton) which would keep/manage this data for you.

Comment: No, it's not. The whole reason we use packages and subroutines is to get as far away as possible from global variables. Using global variables inevitably leads to hard to track down at-a-distance bugs as your codebase grows. The reason for packages and subroutines is to keep namespaces clean, and to reduce this action-at-a-distance. Imagine you have 10 subs, and you add an 11th. In there, you change variable `$x`, but you forgot that `$x` was previously used somewhere else for something else. Now something breaks far away from this new code, and you have to struggle to figure out wtf happened.

Comment: Quoting from http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad 
Really Bad Reasons to Use Global Variables: ... 
    "I don't want to pass it around all the time."